# Trying to access phpmyadmin from remote machine

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have an ubuntu server with mysql.server installes and phpmyadmin, but when i try to access [serverIp]/phpmyadmin i get the ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error, is there any solution to this?

This is my apache.conf file

```
# phpMyAdmin default Apache configuration

Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    DirectoryIndex index.php
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Require all granted
    # limit libapache2-mod-php to files and directories necessary by pma
    <IfModule mod_php7.c>
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
        php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/:/usr/share/javascript/
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

# Disallow web access to directories that don't need it
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/templates>
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Comment: It's probably a firewall issue.

Comment: Timeout means you couldn't even connect at the network level, the Apache configuration is irrelevant.

Comment: With apache running, check `netstat -lt` to see what IP Address apache bound.  If it's `127.0.0.1` change it to `serverIP` or `0.0.0.0`

Comment: @erik258 yes, it was a firewall issue, its solved now, thanks